# Handle exceptions in a rest controller in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, exception

I create REST web-service with Spring Boot. 
I would like to know what is a better way to handle exceptions in a controller. I have seen other questions and didn’t found an answer.

My controller:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> saveMyUser(){
    MyUser myUser = new MyUser(“Anna”);

    //throws SQLException
    MyUserDetails userDetails = userService.saveMyUser(myUser);

    //if successful
    return ResponseBody.ok(userDetails);
}
```

saveMyUser() method of UserService:

```
public MyUserDetails saveUser(MyUser) throws SQLException {...}
```

So at this point I have at least 2 simple options:

1. Add exception to method signature.
   Here I may rely on Spring Boot to pass all information about exception and status code to a client. However do not know if it is a reliable approach.
2. Surround with try/catch and pass all information about exceptions manually.

What is a better simple way?

Comment: do not handle them yourself. let all your methods in controller ``throws Exception`` (you don't care). Then annotate a method with ``@ExceptionHandler``: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html

Comment: you have a number of options: [exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)

Comment: Don't throw SQLExcpetion. That basicallyl means you are using plain JDBC. Iinstead use the `JdbcTempalte` which already handles all of this.

Comment: In additional Spring Boot will then handle the `DataAccessException` thrown by the `JdbcTemplate` as it is an unchecked (aka. `RuntimeException`). If you want to do something specific in this controller or your code yo ucan use an `@ExceptionHandler`.

Comment: @spi Do not want to post it as an answer? That is what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @KirillCh I don't care about reputation. You can just accept Kamil's answer (same as mine). Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an additional class with `@ControllerAdivce` annotation and later you will be able to write custom response logic for each exception e.g:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler({SQLException.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> sqlError(Exception ex) {
  return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Some SQL exception occured");
}
}
```

Also, you can extend [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java) and override the default behavior for mapping from exceptions to HTTP response.

Also, take a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring), it holds very usefull information for your case.

Comment: But when I try to extend from ResponseEntityExceptionHandler as in the material then an annotation @Valid in a controller method stops sending information to a client, only a status code. Do not know why. Your method works just fine.