# how to catch customize exception with resttemplate and springboot?

Tags: spring-boot

i want throw customize exception in server and catch it in client,but it seems the customize exception was convert to HttpServerErrorException.

TestController.java

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String test()  {
            throw new PasswdException("password err");
    }
}
```

PasswdException.java

```
public class PasswdException extends RuntimeException {
    public PasswdException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

RestTest.java

```
public class RestTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try {
           String s = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/test", null, String.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(e instanceof PasswdException){
                System.out.println("..........");
                //do sth
            }
        }

    }
}
```

expected: client exception instance PasswdException,but actual exception is HttpServerErrorException

Comment: Client receives http statuses from a server. Client has no idea about types of your exception. How to handle and set proper statuses based on your custom exception you might see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271092/handle-exceptions-in-a-rest-controller-in-spring-boot

Comment: Thanks,it seems that in previous spring-web(4.x) it can throw custom exception,and catch it in client.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible in terms of REST but you can achieve it by making a contract definition with:
1. Define HTTP error status code for your exception like (BAD_REQUEST is just as more relevant, you can pick any you feel suits):

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason="Wrong password")
public class PasswdException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

2. RestTest (Client) code should check this HTTP error status with something like:

   `if(resp.getStatus().equals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST))`

etc.